# PG::Error: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xfc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, encoding

I'm getting the following ActiveRecord error when certain strings are saved to the database.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xfc
```

I *think* it's happening for this string `Mühldorf`.

I've tried adding `# encoding: utf-8` to the top of my ruby files to solve this, but doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I'm pulling location data using [Ruby Geocoder](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/), and that's where the string is coming from.

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 on Postgres database on Heroku.

Comment: Is the string `Mühldorf` hard-coded in your source file? If it is coming from another source, then please say where.

Comment: Another source (Ruby Geocoder), just updated the question.

Answer (score 18):

A lower case U-umlaut is 0xfc in [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8859-1) (AKA Latin-1) but 0xfc is not a valid UTF-8 character. The problem is that you have a Latin-1 string that you're trying to treat as UTF-8 and PostgreSQL is rightly complaining.

Either fix the data source to send you UTF-8 or, if it will always send you Latin-1, fix the encoding yourself with something like:

```
utf_8_string = latin_1_string.force_encoding('iso8859-1').encode('utf-8')
```

and then work with the `utf_8_string` version.

Comment: after so much struggling, I finally found this. Thank you alot.