# Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, utf-8, error-handling

I'm trying to run a Ruby script, and always getting an error on this line:

```
file_content.gsub(/dr/i,'med')
```

Where I'm trying to replace "dr" by "med".

The error is:

```
program.rb:4:in `gsub': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
```

Why is that, how can I fix this issue?

I'm working on a MAC OS X Yosemite machine, with Ruby 2.2.1p85.

Comment: From the variable name it looks like you are reading the data from a file – is that right? Where does the file come from and how are you reading it? Do you know the actual encoding of the file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Probably your string is not in UTF-8 format, so use

```
if ! file_content.valid_encoding?
  s = file_content.encode("UTF-16be", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?").encode('UTF-8')
  s.gsub(/dr/i,'med')
end
```

See "[Ruby 2.0.0 String#Match ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036821/ruby-2-0-0-stringmatch-argumenterror-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I use the code snippet you provided? Since when I use it immediately in my program, I get : undefined local variable or method `s' for main:Object (NameError). Thanks

Comment: use `file_content ` instead of `s`

Comment: Before the line I show in my question, I have the following line of code: "file_content = IO.read(filename)". I have placed your code after this line, and before the line in my question, and really still having the same problem

Comment: replace `file_content.gsub(/dr/i,'med')` line with my block of code

Comment: @Simplicity you’re using Ruby 2.2, so you can just use the [`scrub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-scrub) method. This technique is really a workaround for older versions that don’t have `scrub`. (But really you should work out what the encoding actually is and convert it properly, otherwise you are losing data).

Comment: For me, this saved me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103433/7365329