# gsub encoding error when running on Linux Docker Container Invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, character-encoding, docker

I have a string I'm converting from `"\r\n"` to `"\n"` line ends using:

```
input.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")
```

When I run it on my Windows host, it works fine. When I run on my Linux host, in a docker container, I get this error:

```
in `gsub': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
```

I am running Ruby 2.2.

Comment: https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher/issues/147

Comment: Tried that, didn't work

Comment: Are you sure you're working on ASCII data? I have a feeling you're operating on [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoded files, which are the default on Windows, but Linux defaults to ASCII instead. Generally you should be using UTF-8 on both sides, it's much more portable. Look for any characters in your file above the 7-bit ASCII barrier (character code 127).

Comment: I am trying to read CSV files, but some users will save CSV files with Excel and some users will save with open office. I need my script to work with windows or linux, and read the files properly no matter what

Comment: If I leave that line out, then I get  Unquoted fields do not allow \r or \n (CSV::MalformedCSVError)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see an example of the data you're working with. Trying to solve encoding errors without actual data is pretty difficult. Simply replacing line-end characters won't generate the error you're seeing so odds are good you're dealing with something else, most likely Win-1252 as @tadman says.

Comment: I fixed it by doing this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877310/invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-argumenterror

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877310/invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-argumenterror

Comment: @Codemiester If you figured it out, you should post an answer to your own question to help someone in the future you may have had exactly the same issue. That helps everyone in the long hall.

Comment: I thought I did, answer didn't get published

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this [Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29877310/invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-argumenterror)

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question as documenting purposses. Looks like this encoding issues are not isolated to a single string for the user, but a known issue in docker as documented here:

https://oncletom.io/2015/docker-encoding/

Seems that some images depends from the original Debian image and:

> [Debian removed their dependency on the locales package](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=636086#3) in 2011. It
>   explains the unavailability of en_US.UTF-8.

That will explain why some docker images on inheriting the system configuration fails to use UTF-8.

```
$ docker run -ti --rm ruby:2.1.5 ruby -e 'puts STDIN.external_encoding'
> US-ASCII
```

locale command in the docker shows empty values where they should be the ones in the system:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm ruby:2.1.5 locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Defining LOCALE variable on initialize should work:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm -e LANG=C.UTF-8 ruby:2.1.5 ruby -e 'puts STDIN.external_encoding'
> UTF-8
```

And even better, you can define it into the Dockerfile

```
#/Dockerfile
FROM ruby:2.1.5
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
```