# importing csv into database returns invalid byte

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file into my database but I get this error:

> PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe2 0x80 0x22

How do I go about fixing this? The CSV comes from an external provider.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102749/pgerror-error-invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8-0xfc

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which encoding your csv-file is. Ask the provider of the file or just experiment with an editor that can switch the encodings.

The you just need to convert the string before parsing it with csv. For example, if it is ISO-8859-15 (Windows Western Europe with Euro) you can convert the string like this:

```
def convert_iso(st)
    st.force_encoding('iso-8859-15').encode('utf-8')
end
```